# Are special member functions noexcept or throw()?

Tags: c++, c++11

The C++11 spec is clear that implicitly-generated special functions (i.e., default constructor, destructor, copy/move constructors, and copy/move assignment operators) have exception specifications. But the spec seems be written only in terms of the now-deprecated *dynamic* exception specifications (i.e., "throw (T1, T2, T3)").  This is backed up by the example in 15.4/14:

```
struct A {
  A();
  A(const A&) throw();
  A(A&&) throw();
  ~A() throw(X);
};
struct B {
  B() throw();
  B(const B&) throw();
  B(B&&) throw(Y);
  ~B() throw(Y);
};
struct D : public A, public B {
  // Implicit declaration of D::D();
  // Implicit declaration of D::D(const D&) throw();
  // Implicit declaration of D::D(D&&) throw(Y);
  // Implicit declaration of D::D() throw(X, Y);
};
```

Notes are not normative, I know, but it's noteworthy that D's copy constructor is declared `throw()` instead of `noexcept`.  It makes a difference, because the behavior of the program is different if a `throw()` is violated versus if a `noexcept` is violated.

The text in 15.4/14 above the example is normative, and it says:

> An implicitly declared special member function (Clause 12) 
>   shall have an exception-specification. If f is an implicitly declared
>   default constructor, copy constructor, move constructor, destructor,
>   copy assignment operator, or move assignment operator, its implicit
>   exception-specification specifies the type-id T if and only if T is
>   allowed by the exception-specification of a function directly invoked
>   by f’s implicit definition; f shall allow all exceptions if any
>   function it directly invokes allows all exceptions, and f shall allow
>   no exceptions if every function it directly invokes allows no
>   exceptions.

Given that only dynamic exception specifications are referred to here, I fear that implicitly-generated special member functions are never declared `noexcept`.  Is that really the case?

Comment: How could they ever be declared `noexcept`? Did you want the compiler to go through your code and check if you never throw exceptions?

Comment: @SethCarnegie: I'd expect the compiler to use `noexcept` if it deduced that the dynamic exception specification would be `throw()`.

Comment: Since "12 [...] A function with a non-throwing exception-specification does not allow any exceptions.", indifferently either of `noexcept` or `throw()` is a valid exception-specification that allows no exceptions. That seems about enough for paragraph 14, which doesn't requiree a dynamic-exception-specification in particular. I'm not sure I grasp the whole picture well enough to make that an answer.

Comment: "It makes a difference, because the behavior of the program is different if a throw() is violated versus if a noexcept is violated."  Really?  How so?

Comment: @Nemo The behaviour of the program differs in the case of a _violation_ of `throw()` vs `noexcept`, i.e. if an exception is actually thrown. `noexcept` calls `std::terminate`, possibly not fully unwinding the stack, in such a case.

Comment: @jogojapan: While a violation of `throw()` calls `std::unexpected` which calls `std::terminate` by default. I suppose it is different in theory.  Does seem like an oversight in the spec.

Comment: In theory, use of `noexcept` instead of `nothrow()` permits compilers to generate better code (see, for example, the discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/comp.std.c++/gs01mc4zBnY/overview)), so it would be unfortunate if implicitly-generated member functions had to use `throw()` instead of `noexcept`.

Answer (score 1):

I do not believe that's the case. The actual requirement is only that "...f shall allow no exceptions if every function it directly invokes allows no exceptions."

As noted just above (§15.4/12):

> An exception-specification is non-throwing if it is of the form `throw()`, `noexcept`, or `noexcept(`*constant-expression*`)` where the *constant-expression* yields `true`. A function with a non-throwing *exception-specification* does not allow any exceptions.

It's not exactly a revelation that a non-throwing exception specification does not allow any exceptions, but I think it's telling that the wording in the description of a non-throwing exception specification is echoed nearly verbatim in the requirement on the implicitly declared special member function. As such, it appears to me that any form of non-throwing exception specification (`throw()` or `noexcept` or `noexcept(<anything that converts to true>)`) is allowed -- and that this was specifically intended, not just an accident of wording.

Comment: I can see how you can read it this way, but given the difference in semantics between `noexcept` and `throw()`, it would be nice if the standard were more precise about which is used to express the notion that the function doesn't throw.